# Why am I getting an "[XCUITest] Failed to receive any data within the timeout: 5000" error when running mobile web tests on iOS real device?

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, appium

I am currently trying to run tests using Appium on a real iOS device, with the pytest and selenium framework. Before running tests, I successfully built the WebDriverAgent onto the device and started the Appium server. After entering the pytest command to start the test the Safari browser in the iOS device opens but the test does not start. I get this error in the Appium logs:

```
[debug] [iProxy@67f2ea78:8100] Closing the connection
[debug] [DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[debug] [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[debug] [XCUITest] Found a remote debugger session. Removing...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Cleaning up listeners
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1639089800521 (14:43:20 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not navigate to webview! Err: Failed to receive any data within the timeout: 5000
[debug] [W3C]     at spinHandles (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/lib/commands/context.js:522:23)
[debug] [W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.navToViewWithTitle (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/lib/commands/context.js:564:3)
[debug] [W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.navToInitialWebview (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:29:5)
[debug] [W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.start (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:479:7)
[debug] [W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.createSession (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:215:7)
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:371:35)
[debug] [W3C] Caused by: Error: Failed to receive any data within the timeout: 5000
[debug] [W3C]     at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-device/lib/plist-service/index.js:67:16)
[debug] [W3C]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
[debug] [W3C]     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 14924 ms - 741
[HTTP] 
[iProxy@67f2ea78:8100] The connection has been closed
```

Has anyone come across this issue and found a resolution?

capabilities = {
"platformName": settings.MOBILE_DEVICE_PLATFORM,
"platformVersion": _platform_version,
"newCommandTimeout": 3000,
"udid": _device_id,
"automationName" = "XCUITest",
"browserName" = "Safari",
"usePrebuiltWDA": True,
"deviceName": "iPhone
}

Appium version: 1.22.1

XCode version: 13.1 (13A1030d)

iOS version on device: 15.1

Node version: 17.0.1

NVM version: 0.39.0

Comment: Is there some code associated with this or do we have to guess what the test looks like. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's causing because of IOSDriver when we access programatically. Android works fine.

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
> remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
> error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
> command. Original error: Failed to receive any data within the
> timeout: 5000

Failed exactly here.

> driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL(remoteUrl.toString()),
> desiredCapabilities);

```
AppiumServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    serviceBuilder.usingAnyFreePort();
    serviceBuilder.usingDriverExecutable(new File(Appium_Node_Path));
    serviceBuilder.withAppiumJS(new File(Appium_JS_Path));
    HashMap<String, String> environment = new HashMap<String,String>();
    environment.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH"));
    serviceBuilder.withEnvironment(environment);
    server = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(serviceBuilder);
    server.start();
    server.isRunning();
driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL(remoteUrl.toString()), desiredCapabilities);
```

> Mac OS version 12.2.1 Xcode version 13.2.1 Appium 1.22.2

No issue with WDA if directly run Appium desktop server works fine.

```
 URL remoteUrl = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new IOSDriver<>(remoteUrl, desiredCapabilities);
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem with Appium 1.22.3.
Node version is root cause of this error. I was using node v18 when I changed it to v16 it worked as expected.

Comment: I see. That could've been it too as I was using node v17. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like @positivecrux I faced same problem with Appium 1.22.3. I was using node v18 when I updated to v16.9.1 it worked as expected.

```
npm install -g n
sudo n stable
node -v
```

or for 2nd line if you get issue you can use specific version

```
sudo n 16.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why or how but my issue was fixed by using Appium Desktop instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).